# Testing React Native with Appium: how to get past "Permit drawing over other apps"?

Tags: appium, react-native

In my initial proof of concept for testing a React Native mobile app using Appium, I noticed that when I load the APK to start my test, I am presented with an Android prompt to "Permit drawing over other apps" as I am creating my AndroidDriver driver.  If I move the slider manually, then click the back button, all is good -- the app loads fully, and my test proceeds.  However, I don't see how to do this with automation using my Appium script because it looks like the driver instantiation will not complete until the slider is moved.

Most people don't see this in Appium testing as it appears to be specific to React Native in dev mode, as seen here...

[image: Android emulator showing slider (highlighted)]

Here's my code where I've put in conditional code to click the slider, but I never get there because it waits at the "driver = ..." line:

```
AndroidDriver driver = null;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    // < defining capabilities (emulator6p) up here...>

    // initialize driver object
    try {
        driver = new AndroidDriver<WebElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), emulator6p); 
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}

@Test
public void test1() throws Exception {
    By BY_slider_permitDrawing = By.id("android:id/switchWidget");
    boolean present = (driver.findElements(BY_slider_permitDrawing).size() == 1);
    if (present) {
        driver.findElement(BY_slider_permitDrawing).click();
        driver.navigate().back();
    }

    WebElement button_begin = driver.findElementByAccessibilityId("button-lets-begin");
    button_begin.click();
}
```

I definitely hear plenty of people say that Appium is a viable solution for React Native testing, and really need to get over this hump.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

jph

p.s. In case it wasn't really clear, the test does NOT hang at the "driver = " line if I am not loading the APK from scratch, but I will need to do that for CI testing in the future.

Comment: It will come in the debug version. Release version does not have this problem

Comment: Paras, I assume you're referring to the release/production version of the react native app.  I need to use the debug version because the strategy for seeding the various components with IDs is the following...                   
    testProps = (id) => {
        if (__DEV__) {
          return {testID: id, accessibilityLabel: id}
        }
     }

Answer (score 0):

Setting right capabilities helped me to run Appium tests in Debug mode on Android:

```
{
  ...
  "appWaitPackage": "com.android.settings, com.yourPackage",
  "appWaitActivity": "com.android.settings.Settings$AppDrawOverlaySettingsActivity, com.yourPackage.MainActivity",
}
```

Replace `yourPackage` with your real package name used in Android app. Some docs here: https://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps/#android-only

Comment: Thank you very much for the capabilities suggestion, but wouldn't that require me to still click the slider for the automation to proceed?

Comment: @JoeHennessey no, in my case it switches automatically to the `appActivity` provided in capabilities. No extra code required.